# Shortcut key to clear console in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the shortcut key to clear console in Eclipse or how can it be configured?
Any work-arounds to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not appear to be a way, as there's a bug filled regarding this issue on [bugs.eclipse.org](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=54909).

Comment: since it's been a while, updating to note that the bug is still languishing.

Answer (score 59):

I know this thread is already 3 years old, but if someone is still looking for it, in Indigo the shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd> - <kbd>F10</kbd> followed by <kbd>r</kbd>.

Cheers.

Comment: For anyone is wondering why this doesn't work - Make sure to switch to the console window first. You can do this with Ctrl + F7 to open 'views' and continue pressing F7 to progress to select the console.

Comment: on kepler on my mac, its shift-F10, then c (for clear), then enter

Comment: In Eclipse Neon on Windows 10 it is Shift-F10 then 'r' again (still?), as posted in the answer.

Comment: @sjgp yes, it still is. It seems they don't want to implement a shortcut for this

Comment: I was trying to make for some faster combination like: "Alt" + "c", but without success. Any idea how to make it?

Comment: Tested on Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) and it works the same way!

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution for the wiping the console in an Eclipse IDE. It uses the Robot class. Please see code below and caption for explanation:

```
   import java.awt.AWTException;
   import java.awt.Robot;
   import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

   public void wipeConsole() throws AWTException{
        Robot robbie = new Robot();
        //shows the Console View
        robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        robbie.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
        robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Q);
        robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);
        robbie.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);

        //clears the console
        robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F10);
        robbie.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robbie.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F10);
        robbie.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        robbie.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
    }
```

Assuming you haven't changed the default hot key settings in Eclipse and import those java classes, this should work.

Comment: That's neat. I use AHK to make a ton of scripts that make my life a little easier one at a time. I will definitely be adding this to my toolbox.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 18, Eclipse Oxigen 2, I 'walked' with: ALT + W + V + DOWN + ENTER

Answer (score 2):

This thread is 7 years old now, but I constantly need to clean the console so i can get work done. Thanks to sbanders I made this AutoHotKey script:

```
#`::
WinGetTitle, Title, ahk_class SWT_Window0
if InStr(Title, "Eclipse") {
  WinActivate, ahk_class SWT_Window0
  Send +!q
  Sleep, 1200
  Send c
  Send +{F10}r
}
return
```

What this means is the following.

- When the user presses <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>Backtic</kbd> (this can easily be changed to a different hotkey),
- If an Eclipse window exists
- Activate that window and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd> (opens navigation context menu)
- *Wait 1.2 seconds* (wait time probably depends on system specs)
- Press <kbd>c</kbd> (Will focus on console view)
- Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> (Clears console)
- *End script*

It's a very handy script for coders who don't like clicking so I thought I'd share it.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> followed by <kbd>C</kbd> to set focus to console.

Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> followed by <kbd>R</kbd> to clear it.

Answer (score 1):

When I right-click inside the console window and select 'clear' it clears my console. I'm using Windows 10.

If you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> that works.

Comment: Using a mouse is not a "shortcut key"

Comment: @jonincanada: Shift+F10 is the shortcut key for opening the context menu. so no need to "right-click".