# How can I set a key binding in Eclipse for clearing the console?

Tags: eclipse, key-bindings

I´ve been looking in the Internet for a way to establish a key binding in Eclipse for clearing the console, but I haven´t found a way to do it. How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672428/shortcut-key-to-clear-console-in-eclipse . You can also click the Console window and press **shift/F10** then **r** on windows. Not ideal, but possibly better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by [using eclipse commands](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommands/article.html). Read up on the [eclipse commands framework](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_Command_Framework) to create key bindings.

Here the syntax for creating a key binding:

```
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
<key
      commandId="z.ex.view.keybindings.eatTaco"
      contextId="z.ex.view.keybindings.contexts.taco"
      schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
      sequence="CTRL+3">
</key>
```